# What does \p{P} mean?

Tags: java, regex

So, I was messing around with regex to convert sentences into pig latin, and decided to extend the assignment to allow for punctuation.
I was looking for a regex that allowed for me to replace the punctuation with an empty string and found `myString.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");` and was curious as to what the \p and {P} actually do here. Other similar questions have used `"\\p{Z}"` to replace whitespace, which leads me to think the \p is searching for whatever is inside of the brackets.

Anyways any clarifications or directions to documentation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The javadoc explains this:   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: don't know how I missed this. Thank you

Comment: If I search the Javadocs I don't find `\p{P}` just `\p{Punctuation}` and `\p{Print}`. Similarly I searched the referenced answer which is already supposed to answer this question and also don't find a reference to `\p{P}`

Comment: The linked question ("[What does this regex mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/90527)") doesn't specifically mention the punctuation Unicode category, but does state that `\p` is for Unicode categories, which addresses what `\p` means (which is asked in this question). Whether it's a duplicate depends in part on whether this question is primarily asking for an explanation for `\p`, or what the 'P' category is (in which case, this question is actually asking 2 questions, one of which is a duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

In PCRE regular expressions

- `\p{P}` is "Any punctuation character"
- `\p{Z}` is "Any whitespace character"

See the "EXPLANATION" section on the right: https://regex101.com/r/ZFIKpv/1